# How to mix 2 keying nodes in the compositor to keep the alpha channel from both?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How do I mix two keys in the compositor to form an image that uses both the keyed out parts?  Movie Clip node > Keying node > Viewer = green screen removed; then same Movie Clip node > different Keying node > Viewer = blue markers removed.  How do I combine these?  I am trying to remove the background, and isolate the people in the foreground and have an alpha channel background.

edit: I don't really know what to search for, can anyone maybe share a link or just tell me the words to search for in Google?

Do I need to render out 1, then go back and re-render out the second?  I feel like there is a way, similar to render layers, but with images/movies, sorry if this doesn't make sense, I will edit it when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put one into the other as so - that way each node changes the previous  [image: answer]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the Keying node.  Adding the second Keying node just seems to change the color of the background more than key it out (like it is when it's solo).  I am about to try that with the color key nodes though, thanks.

Comment: Using the **color key nodes** got it very close, but I think I'll have to use the **keying node** and render out a sequence and then re-key out the other color and render a second time; the **keying node** seems to work better for the different shades of color/shadows/ movement/etc., than the **color key node**. TY for the reply, I might end up using your example, still testing stuff out. : )

Answer (score 0):

Did you work this out @Policestate. I'm trying to do something similar in that I've isolated all the elements I require, and I want to then combine those Keying nodes into a single output-able stream.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/179895)

Comment: No it doesn't, but I lacked the reputation to simply comment as a new user. Happy for this to be moved as a comment to the thread above.

Comment: Note to self, I should search through the other nodes types for the following: Merge
Layer
Combine
Add + Max + Plus : Scene